# Serial print and sensor readings halts

Tags: serial, sensors, c++, robotics

I'm trying to write a state machine for my robot.

While the robot is moving around I would like to read the values of the sensors, but after some time the reading stops working.

For the first half hour it's ok, then I don't know what changes.

It looks like it halts when jumping from one state to another, or when the sensor value has a big jump...

I tried to move the debugOutput function inside the main loop, but the behavior is the same..

In addition to the serial halting, also the state machine itself seems to stop working good, since even if the sensor value change, the state is not updated..

Could you please help me with this? 
Thanks a lot!

Here is the code:

```
    // motor one
    int enA = 13;
    int in1 = 12;
    int in2 = 11;
    // motor two
    int enB = 9;
    int in3 = 10;
    int in4 = 8;

    int sens1 = 0; //ingresso sensore bobina 1
    int sens2 = 1; //ingresso sensore bobina 2

    float soglia_barriera_norm = 1.5; 
    float soglia_barriera_scarico = 390;


    // define the states
    #define DRIVE_FORWARD     0
    #define TURN_LEFT         1
    #define RADDRIZZA         2
    #define SCARICO           3 //Scarico cerca il filo

    int state = 3; //to start from state 3


    void setup()
    {
      // set all the motor control pins to outputs
      pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(53, OUTPUT);
      Serial.begin(9600);

    }

    //------------------------ LETTURA SENSORI ---------------------------
    //average of n readings

    float sensorReadDX(int n_medie) {
      int i, temp = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < n_medie; i++) {
        int sensorValue1 = analogRead(sens1);
        temp += sensorValue1;
      }
      float volt = (temp / n_medie);
      return volt;
    }

    float sensorReadSX(int n_medie) {
      int i, temp = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < n_medie; i++) {
        int sensorValue2 = analogRead(sens2);
        temp += sensorValue2;
      }
      float volt2 = (temp / n_medie);
      return volt2;
    }

    float differenza(float volt1, float volt2) {
      float D = volt1 - volt2;
      return D;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------

    //----------- MOTOR MOVEMENTS ---------------------------------------------

    void moto_dx_forward(int vel) {
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
      analogWrite(enA, vel);
    }

    void moto_dx_backward(int vel) {
      digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      analogWrite(enA, vel);
    }

    void moto_sx_forward(int vel) {
      digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
      analogWrite(enB, vel);
    }

    void moto_sx_backward(int vel) {
      digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
      analogWrite(enB, vel);
    }

    // to stop motors
    void moto_dx_stop() {
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      analogWrite(enA, 0);
    }

    void moto_sx_stop() {
      digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
      analogWrite(enB, 0);
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------

    void debugOutput() {
      Serial.print(millis());
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(sensorReadSX(50));
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(sensorReadDX(30));
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.println(state);
    }


    void stateMachine() {
      float sensSX = sensorReadSX(30);
      float sensDX = sensorReadDX(30);

      if (state == DRIVE_FORWARD) {
        debugOutput();

        if (sensSX <= soglia_barriera_norm || sensDX <= soglia_barriera_norm) {
          moto_dx_forward(255);
          moto_sx_forward(255);
        } else {
          state = RIMBALZA;
        }
      }

      else if (state == SCARICO) {
        debugOutput();
        if (sensorReadSX(50) < soglia_barriera_scarico){ //|| sensorReadDX(20) < soglia_barriera_scarico) {
          moto_dx_forward(255);
          moto_sx_forward(255);
        } else {
          moto_dx_stop(); //ferma i due motori e poi raddrizza
          moto_sx_stop();
          state = RADDRIZZA;
        }
      }

      else if (state == RADDRIZZA) {
        debugOutput();
         while ( sensorReadDX(30) <= 490){ 
          //ruota su se stesso
          moto_sx_stop();
          moto_dx_forward(255);
        }

        moto_dx_stop();
        moto_sx_stop();
      }

    }

    void loop() {
      stateMachine();

    }
```

Comment: Try outputting the current state.  Is there any logic which can change from the RADDRIZA state to any other?  It sort of looks that it could become stuck there with both motors off.

Comment: no, at the moment when RADDRIZZA is finished it stays there with motor stopped.. however I found the problem, it stopped outputting because during the while ( sensorReadDX(30) <= 490) it doesn't execute what's outside the loop!